# не распознаёт цифры по примеру https://keras.io/examples/vision/mnist_convnet/

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, искусственный-интеллект, распознавание

Есть пример обучения ИИ по распознаванию рукописных цифр
https://keras.io/examples/vision/mnist_convnet/
Но он работает только на имеющихся данных, на которых была обучена нейросеть, а не на предоставленных.
Я взял готовый пример из указанной ссылки, но добавил в конце предоставления сетке своих рукописных цифр, и эта нейросеть с ней не справляется.
Весь вопрос в том, что в примере сетке скармливается 60000 примеров рукописных цифр, и по логике сетка должна расползновать похожие цифры ввода. Но почему она не работает в моем случае?
Вот код, скопирован из  Jupyter Notebook

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Canvas, Button

# Model / data parameters
num_classes = 10
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

# Load the data and split it between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# Scale images to the [0, 1] range
x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255
# Make sure images have shape (28, 28, 1)
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)
print("x_train shape:", x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], "train samples")
print(x_test.shape[0], "test samples")


# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=input_shape),
        layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.5),
        layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)

model.summary()
batch_size = 128
epochs = 15
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Test loss:", score[0])
print("Test accuracy:", score[1])


import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Canvas, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import io
# Создаем окно
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Рисование и сохранение изображения")
# Создаем холст для рисования
scale = 10
canvas_width = 28 * scale
canvas_height = 28 * scale
canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, bg="white")
canvas.pack()
# Создаем изображение и холст для рисования
img = Image.new("L", (28, 28), 255)  # 255 - белый цвет
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
# Переменные для отслеживания движения мыши
prev_x, prev_y = None, None
# Функция для рисования
def paint(event):
    global prev_x, prev_y
    x, y = event.x // scale, event.y // scale
    if prev_x and prev_y:
        draw.line((prev_x, prev_y, x, y), fill=0, width=1)
        canvas.create_line(prev_x * scale, prev_y * scale, x * scale, y * scale, fill="black", width=2)
    prev_x, prev_y = x, y
# Функция для сброса переменных при отпускании кнопки мыши
def release(event):
    global prev_x, prev_y
    prev_x, prev_y = None, None
# Привязываем события
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", release)
# Функция для обработки нажатия кнопки "OK"
def save_image():
    # Масштабируем изображение до 28x28
    img_data = img.resize((28, 28))
    # img_data = img_data.rotate(-90)  # Повернуть изображение
    img_data.save("/home/misha/Изображения/temp.png")
    root.destroy()
# Создаем кнопку "OK"
ok_button = Button(root, text="OK", command=save_image)
ok_button.pack()
# Запускаем приложение Tkinter
root.mainloop()
# Загрузите ваше изображение и измените его размер до 28x28 пикселей
image = Image.open('/home/misha/Изображения/temp.png')  # Замените "your_image.jpg" на путь к вашему изображению
image = image.resize((28, 28))
# Получим размер изображения
width, height = image.size
# Выведем размер изображения
print("Width:", width)
print("Height:", height)
# Загрузите изображение
image = cv2.imread('/home/misha/Изображения/temp.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
# Проверьте количество каналов
num_channels = image.shape[2] if len(image.shape) == 3 else 1
if num_channels == 1:
    print("Изображение черно-белое.")
else:
    print("Изображение цветное.")
# Загрузите ваше изображение
image = Image.open("/home/misha/Изображения/temp.png")
# Преобразуйте изображение в формат NumPy и выполните масштабирование
your_image = np.array(image)  # Преобразование в NumPy-массив
your_image = your_image.astype("float32") / 255  # Масштабирование пикселей в диапазон [0, 1]
# Убедитесь, что изображение имеет размерность (28, 28, 1)
# your_image = your_image.reshape((28, 28, 1))
your_image = np.expand_dims(your_image, axis=-1)
plt.imshow(image, cmap='binary')
plt.axis('off')
# Выполните инференс
predictions = model.predict(np.array([your_image]))
# Результат predictions будет вероятностным распределением по классам.
# Для получения конкретного числа (предсказанной цифры) можно воспользоваться:
predicted_digit = np.argmax(predictions)
print("Predicted digit:", predicted_digit)
```